# Best way to convert a case class to a js.Object

Tags: scala.js

Say I have a case class:

```
case class Name(first: String, last: String)
val n1 = Name("John", "Doe")
val n2 = Name("Mary", "Doe")
```

and I have a java script object:

```
@js.native
trait MyJSObject extends js.Object { 
  def add(name: js.Object): Unit = js.native 
}
```

such that name should be of the format

```
{"first":"John","last":"Doe"}
```

What is the best way to convert my case object to a js.Object?

I know this can be achieved doing a upickle.write() to convert it to a json String so I guess my question is is this the best way?

Comment: Offhand, I suspect that upickle.write is the most *convenient* way to deal with it.  You could probably get a somewhat more elegant solution using Shapeless, but that would be much more effort without much obvious benefit...

Comment: Having said that how does one convert a json string to a js.Object?

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but I suspect that js.eval(String) would do the trick.

Comment: Also, I should check: do you care about these being conventional Scala case classes?  If their purpose is *mainly* for Scala interop, then you should probably use @ScalaJSDefined instead -- that's kind of what it's for.

Comment: Yes this are case classes served up by my jvm so I cannot refer to a scala annotation in that part of my project from my understanding.

Answer (score 11):

If you control the case class, you can just add the `@JSExportAll` annotation to it:

```
@JSExportAll
case class Name(first: String, last: String)
```

This will create properties named `first` and `last`. Note that this is **not** the same as a simple object. However, depending on what the `add` method does, it is sufficient (and much more lightweight than converting to JSON and parsing again).

In case you need to cross compile the case class, you can include the `scalajs-stubs` library in your JVM project. It will provide dummy annotations (that are not written to `.class` files).

If you need a `js.Object`, you can use the export typechecker:

```
val x = Name("foo", "bar")
js.use(x).as[js.Object]
```

This will even work with a trait that defines the fields you need:

```
@js.native
trait Options extends js.Object {
  def first: String = js.native
  def last: String = js.native
}

val x = Name("foo", "bar")
js.use(x).as[Options]
```

The `js.use(x).as` call will fail, if there is a mismatch between the types (i.e. if `Options` defines a field that `Name` doesn't define).

Comment: But how do I convert a Name instance to a js.Object?

Comment: And this solution won't work in my case, as my case class is also used on the jvm side. So I cannot make any references to the scala.scalajs package there if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Could you add some information about limitations of this approach? What I noticed (as of Scala.js 0.6.22) is that the field names in the serialized object get `$1` or `$smth` suffix. If the resulting object needs to mutate the fields, they have to be `var`s explicitly. Also `.as[js.Object]` won't work, because it requires a trait.

Comment: Re the `$1` or `$smth` suffix in the previous comment, note that the original names are also captured in the object as indicated in this answer. So, continuing with the `case class Name(first: String, last: String)` example, besides `first$1` and `last$1`, you should also get the `first` and `last` properties.

Comment: What is `use` in Scala.js 1.x?

Comment: `js.use(x).as` has been removed in Scala.js 1.x

Comment: @gzm0 so what is the Scala.js 1.x approach for converting `case class` to `js.Object`?

Comment: `@JSExportAll` still works the same way. But there is currently not type checking facility to check exports against a JS trait. (but you can simply cast: `x.asInstanceOf[js.Object]`). If you feel that type checked exports are valuable / necessary, maybe you can file a bug against Scala.js so we can discuss there? (https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues).

Answer (score -1):

With [uPickle](https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle-pprint):

```scala
val jsValue: Js.Value = upickle.Types.writeJs[Name](n1)
val jsObject: js.Any = upickle.json.writeJs(jsValue).asInstanceOf[js.Any]
```